# How to print all of the results from scanf data in loop

Tags: c

I have this code snippet.

```
int a, item_amount;
float price;

printf("How many item do you want: ");
scanf("%i", &item_amount);

for(a=1; a<= item_amount; a = a + 1)
    {
        printf("Item %i: ", a);
        scanf("%s", item);
        printf("Price: RM ");
        scanf("%f", &price);
    }

for(a=1; a<= item_amount; a = a + 1)
    {
        printf("\nItem: %s",item);
        printf("\nPrice: %f", price);
    }
```

The thing is, I'm trying to print out the items' name and their prices as a receipt, but it only print out the last item and price. The output will show like this:

```
How many item do you want: 2
Item 1: Box
Price: 12.20
Item 2: Book
Price: 2.30
```

(*The receipt will be shown as below*)

```
Item: Book
Price: 2.30
Item: Book
Price: 2.30
```

How can I make it print all of the scanned item and not repeating the item like the one above?

Comment: You only have on variable for price and one for item. That is wahat you print, repeatedly. Where do you expect the other info to survive between the two loops?

Comment: Have you already learned about arrays?

Comment: Can you define a maximuim number of items your billing should support? I.e. can we e.g. assume that only at most tem items will be sold? Consider allowing this for the time being, fixing your immediate problem and then, when it is fixed, extend your program to accept more items.

Comment: Use char array for the item and float array for price. i.e item[No_of_item][size_of_item] and price[No_of_item].

Comment: Note that in C, idiomatic loops run `for (int a = 0; a < item_amount; a++)`, starting at zero, counting up to but not including the maximum, and using an increment operator (`++a` is also OK; it's even preferred in C++).  This works well with array indexing — the lowest index in an array is `0`, and given `int array[item_amount];`, correctly accesses only elements with indexes from `0` to `item_amount - 1`.  It's perfectly OK to deviate from this when necessary, but you should only do so when it _is_ necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the values in arrays so that you don't overwrite previous values in the next loop - something like:

```
int a, item_amount;

float price[10];      // array - max 10 elements
char item[10][256];   // array - max 10 elements - max 255 chars in name

printf("How many item do you want: ");
scanf("%i", &item_amount);

for (a = 0; a < item_amount; a = a + 1)  // Start from zero
{
        printf("Item %i: ", a+1);
        scanf("%s", item[a]);        // Never use %s - see below
        printf("Price: RM ");
        scanf("%f", &price[a]);
}

for (a = 0; a < item_amount; a = a + 1)  // Start from zero
{
        printf("\nItem: %s",item[a]);
        printf("\nPrice: %f", price[a]);
}
```

Notice that the above code miss a lot of the checks that you should do. For instance:

1. Always check the return value from `scanf`
2. Never do `scanf("%s", ...)` it may cause overflow. Use `fgets` or at least do `scanf("%255s...` Also consider what happens if a user inputs a name longer than 255 chars...
3. Check that the amount of items is less or equal to 10.